# Best HTML/CSS model for table-like layout

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I would like to create a following layout in my project.

My main rectangular element could have 3 vertical columns. The middle column is separated into 3 rows. The top row is separated into 2 columns, bottom row is separated into 4 columns, etc ...

You can imagine it as a table with a very irregular rows / columns / subrows / subcolumns ... At the lowest level there are "cells", size of each cell depends on its content, each cell will have some content. I want to have equal space between cells (e.g. 1em)

My current idea is to make a tree structure by combining DIVs with display=block and display=inline-block. But if I set margin=1em; margin of cell will be added to margins of parents and will look ugly. Is there any better solution? I've heard I should avoid tables, colspan etc.

Comment: You should not avoid tables if the actual thing you're doing is a table. Only doing layout with them is to be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use such a structure, you could add a class you the leaf divs (the cells) so that you can apply a css statement where you differentiate the margin from other divs in the structure.

Something like:

```
.cell-div {
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2z6nzxjr/

Comment: I need margin=1em between each two adjacent cells. But if If two cells have different parents, the distance between them would be 2em, 3em etc... am I right? I need this margin to be independent on number of parents.

Comment: If you set just the margin of JUST the cells to 0.5em, then adjacent cells will be 1em away from each other.

Comment: @IvanKuckir I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! When parent divs have margin=0 and only leaves have margin, it may work. But I must have 3 kinds of containers (rows, columns, cells) instead of 2. I edited it a little http://jsfiddle.net/2z6nzxjr/1/. Is there any way to make the HTML structure simpler?

Comment: @IvanKuckir Well, given what you want to do I don't think it can get much simpler than that, although I've edited your fiddle commenting out some 'div': [check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z6nzxjr/2/). Any way you could consider using some other plugin like [Masonry](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) to get the effect you've described :)